# Still setup with barbed connectors

Tags: equipment

I would to set up a boiler connected to a cornelius keg which would work as thumper    than to a condenser all with barbed connectors such as is on the cornelius keg....will it work to pass thru the gasses....I'm sure that larger pipes would work better   but I would like to start this way if it would work...what do you think ?

Comment: err...is this question about brewing or about distillation?

Comment: Hi....It's a  distillation set up question. ...the connections would be the same one as on the cornelius keg...from the still to the corny as thumper and than to condenser. ...basic question will the 1/4 inch hose and connectors pass enough vapor